# replace a part of a string using regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to parse a lot of text and replace a specific part of a tag by ***.

In more details  i want to replace the first part of the email in the tag below by *** :

```
From: abcdef@mydomaine.com
```

i want it to be:

```
From: ***@mydomaine.com
```

keep in mind that this tag could be like:

```
From: abcdef@mydomaine.com
```

or

```
From: <abcdef@mydomaine.com>
```

or

```
From: hello bla bla <abcdef@mydomaine.com>
```

and i want to replace always the first part of the email in this tag by ***.
i tried with preg_replace but i am not good enouph with regular expressions

Comment: why everybody downvoting the question? is it not a good question ? not a clear question or what? please give a comment so i can avoid this next time :)

Comment: I haven't voted but it is good to show an attempt you've made to resolve the issue (no pointing in us giving an answer you already tried).

Comment: i was really ashamed to show the horrible things i did. However i will includ my tries next time. thank you for telling me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following pattern

```
(From:)([^<@]+<)?[^@]+(@)
```

and replace it with

```
$1$2***$3
```

Details:

- `(From:)` matches the string `From:` literally capturing it into the first group (`$1`)
- `([^<@]+<)?` matches some text up to the first occurrence of `<`. Since this part is optional, `?` is used. The match is captured in the second group (`$2`)
- `[^@]+` matches any characters up to first `@`
- `(@)` matches `@` literally and captures it into the third group (`$3`)

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/KDzb8z/1